# Bind Dictionary to DataGridComboBoxColumn WPF

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

Helo guys..

My idea is make use DataGrid as a mapper template, first the grid will load data from, let say "Table A", whis one of the colum will display data from let say "Table B"

i have a "Table B" like this:

```
fieldtype_id | fieldtype_name
     1             int
     2             varchar
     3             date
```

I want to display this table in wpf Datagrid, using DataGridComboBoxColumn.

so, i create a wpf window and datagrid inside it, below is the XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,123,0,176" Name="dataGrid1" Width="1000" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding" CurrentCellChanged="dataGrid1_CurrentCellChanged">

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                             Header="Field Type" Width="200" 
                             DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                             SelectedValueBinding="{Binding fieldtypeSS, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             SelectedValuePath="{Binding fieldtype_id}">

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=fieldtype_id}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=fieldtype_id}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>


        </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

and then, i create a class:

```
public class cMapHeader
{
    public int fieldtypeSS { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> fieldtype_id { get; set; }
}
```

then, populate the table in using method that i've created before

```
//## Get MysqlFieldType
//## dboperation.dtQueries is my method to populate data, and return as DataTable
Dictionary<string, string> mysqlFieldType = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (DataRow row in dboperation.dtQueries("SELECT fieldtype_id, fieldtype_name FROM mysql_Fieldtype ").Rows)
{
    mysqlFieldType.Add(row["fieldtype_id"].ToString(), row["fieldtype_name"] as string);
}
```

Next, Fill the grid

```
gridMapHeader = new ObservableCollection<cMapHeader>()
        {
           new cMapHeader(){fieldtypeSS="1",fieldtype_id=mysqlFieldType},
           new cMapHeader(){fieldtypeSS="2",fieldtype_id=mysqlFieldType}

        };
dataGrid1.BeginInit();

dataGrid1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding
      {
         Source = gridMapHeader
      });
```

what become problem is, the cell that should contain fieldtypeSS doesnt show, but when in edit mode, DataGridComboBoxColumn show value that i want correctly (only shows fieldtype_name of "Table B").

then the second problem is, when the cell lost its focus, the value that have been selected from DataGridComboBoxColumn is lost..

can anyone help me?

really appreciate any help :D

Thx b4

Answer (score 1):

To solve both of your problems, your:

> SelectedValuePath="{Binding fieldtype_id}"

should be:

> SelectedValuePath="fieldtype_id"